# My Java Files in Android Studio Destroyed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My codes were correct a few days ago.
Until today I opened one of the files and watched my code have been erased and Android Studio wrote these in place of my code:

```
<application>
  <component name="ActionsCollector">
    <counts>
      <entry action="$Copy" count="6" />
      <entry action="$Delete" count="21" />
      <entry action="$Paste" count="12" />
      <entry action="$SelectAll" count="6" />
      <entry action="$Undo" count="357" />
      <entry action="Android.RunAndroidAvdManager" count="2" />
      <entry action="Android.SyncProject" count="3" />
      <entry action="CloseAllEditorsButActive" count="2" />
      <entry action="CloseContent" count="13" />
      <entry action="CodeCompletion" count="115" />
      <entry action="DialogOkAction Enter" count="11" />
      <entry action="EditorBackSpace" count="3135" />
      <entry action="EditorChooseLookupItem" count="1615" />
      <entry action="EditorCopy" count="127" />
      <entry action="EditorCut" count="86" />
      <entry action="EditorDelete" count="31" />
      <entry action="EditorDeleteToWordStart" count="3" />
      <entry action="EditorDown" count="1291" />
      <entry action="EditorDownWithSelection" count="1" />
    </counts>
  </component>
  ...
```

The above code replaces the Java code.
And the following code has replaced to my xml code:

```
<application>
<component name="RecentProjectsManager">
<option name="recentPaths">
  <list>
    <option value="D:/Android Studio/Sorud" />
  </list>
</option>
<option name="openPaths">
  <list>
    <option value="D:/Android Studio/Sorud" />
  </list>
</option>
<option name="lastPath" value="D:/Android Studio/Sorud" />
<option name="pid" value="" />
<option name="additionalInfo">
  <map>
    <entry key="D:/Android Studio/Sorud">
      <value>
        <RecentProjectMetaInfo>
          <option name="build" value="AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338" />
          <option name="productionCode" value="AI" />
          <option name="binFolder" value="$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/bin" />
          <option name="projectOpenTimestamp" value="1567522772894" />
          <option name="buildTimestamp" value="1539049499128" />
        </RecentProjectMetaInfo>
      </value>
    </entry>
  </map>
</option>
<option name="lastProjectLocation" value="D:/Android Studio" />
</component>
</application>
```

I also used **Local history**, but to no avail.

I alse used **invalidate and restart**, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions which can help you to resolve your issues.

> **Solutions:-** (use one by one if issue not solved)

**1.**

-> Remove .gradle, .idea, .build file.
[image: Mark with Yellow]

-> Click on Sync Project With Gradle Files (Path:- File/Sync Project With Gradle Files).

-> Click on Rebuild Project (Path:- Build/Rebuild Project).

**2.**

-> Restart your android studio clicking Invalidate Caches/Restart (Path:- File/Invalidate Caches/Restart).

**3.** (this solution will delete caches of your android studio)

-> close android studio

-> Delete android Studio's caches from C drive

- Path: `C:\Users\admin\.AndroidStudioX.Y\system\caches` (where `X.Y` is your version. For example: `3.4`)

-> start an android studio and check your project.

Comment: What do you mean by the first step, the files specified in this image:  http://s5.picofile.com/file/8372978900/Untitled.png

Comment: @Reza no I mean to say .gradle and .idea file which will display when you change Android to Project. wait I am adding an image.

Comment: I don't see the picture. Where's the link?

Comment: @Reza I added image below it

Comment: try this, Right click on SampleProject, go to Local History, If there are local histories available, click on any one, see if there’s your data available, right click, revert.

Comment: @Bhaven Shah I'm sorry. I do not see. Can you copy your link to your answer?

Comment: @Bhaven Shah Oh Thanks My friends

Comment: ah. i did all the steps but still lots of files: http://s2.picofile.com/file/8373082668/Untitled.png

Comment: @Reza have you try last step perfectly ? I think it will work definitely

Comment: @Bhaven Shah  I did all the steps. Even Step 3. But the files failed

Comment: @Reza please add your Gradle files.

Comment: @Bhaven Shah Where?

Comment: With both step 2 and 3, it works for me. Use "Invalidate Caches/Restart" to exit Android Studio, Android Studio will go to start window (which you can select open which project), now, just close it, then go to delete Android Studio cache.